# How do I automatically create desktop environment upon boot of a Windows Server 2012 instance on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, windows-terminal-services

I'm currently running a group of c3.large Windows Server 2012 instances on Amazon EC2.

The project we're working on is a little different, we have a Node.js script running that periodically polls for jobs via a messaging queue.  Each job opens a .jar file to open a user interface on the windows desktop.  Our .jar file then performs a series of actions (which involves taking screenshots of the current window), terminates, then the Node.js uploads the results to MongoDb and Amazon S3.  The Java application (.jar) requires a desktop session to be active in order to function properly (so I don't think a Service would be much use) - kind of like how automated UI testing would require an active desktop.

The infrastructure works great!  However, one big issue is the desktop environment.  Upon launching a new instance via the EC2 management console, the desktop environment doesn't exist until I manually start a remote desktop connection from my local machine (thus creating the desktop for our software to run).  This isn't practical for scalability reasons, ideally I would like to be able to programatically start/stop instances according to demand.

I've tried a number of things; including `<powershell>` commands in the EC2 user-data, using a VNC server and tweaked a couple of settings within the Windows machine itself... all to no avail.

Does anybody know of a technique/setting where by a desktop environment is created upon launch of an EC2 Windows Server 2012 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure the machine for automatic logon.  The console session will then be logged in with the credentials you specify each time the machine boots.

See [Launching multiple ec2 windows servers with auto logon from a custom AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357313/launching-multiple-ec2-windows-servers-with-auto-logon-from-a-custom-ami) for an example of how to configure such a thing.  Basically, you are just using the [Auto logon registry values](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231), but with some workarounds to use them while still syspreping a host.

Comment: Thanks!  I did try auto login registry vars, but that didn't work.  But with any luck, the additional setup might work.

Comment: Worked with excellent results!  Thank you for the heads up!